# Простейшая задача на потоки. Segmentation fault

Tags: linux, c, многопоточность, строки

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t mtx; //переменная мьютекса
typedef struct
{
    char slovo[20];
    char str[20];
    int res;
    int col_words;
} pthrData;


void* process(void* thread_data)
{
    pthrData* data = (pthrData*)
                     thread_data; //создаем указатель на структуру
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
    printf("tread is work\n");
    char* instr;
    double proc;
    data->col_words++; //количество слов
    instr = strstr(data->str, data->slovo); //ищем слово в строке

    if (instr != NULL)
    {
        data->res += strlen(data->slovo); //считаем символы
    }

    proc = (data->res + data->col_words - 1) * 100 / strlen(
               data->str); //вычисляем процент
    printf("%.2lf", proc);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
    usleep(50000);
}

void main(void)
{
    pthread_mutex_init(&mtx, NULL);
    char S1[20], S2[20];
    char sp[10] = " ";
    char* istr;
    int res = 0, col_w = 0, tmp, i = 0;
    double proc;
    printf("Enter S1, S2\n");
    gets(S1);
    gets(S2);

    if (strlen(S1) <= strlen(S2))
    {
        istr = strtok(S1, sp);

        while (istr != NULL)
        {
            col_w++; //считаем количество слов
            istr = strtok(NULL, sp);
        }

        printf("tre");
        printf("%d", col_w);
        pthread_t* threads = (pthread_t*) malloc(col_w * sizeof(
                                 pthread_t)); //выделяем память под переменные потоков
        pthrData* threadData = (pthrData*) malloc(col_w * sizeof(
                                   pthrData)); //выделяем память под структуру, для отправки в функцию потока

        for (int i = 0; i < col_w; i++)
        {
            strncpy(threadData[i].slovo, istr, 20);
            strncpy(threadData[i].str, S2, 20);
            threadData[i].res = 0;
            threadData[i].col_words = 0;
            pthread_create(&(threads[i]), NULL, process,
                           &threadData[i]); // создаем поток
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < col_w; i++)
        {
            pthread_join(threads[i], NULL); // блокируем потоки
        }

        free(threads); // чистим память
        free(threadData);// чистим память
    }

    return 0;
}
```

> Сравнение строк произвольного содержания и вывод процента схожести

Ошибка - Segmentation fault. На стадии компиляции выдает следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: То есть оно всё-таки собралось?

Comment: А вы не хотите для начала добиться компиляции без предупреждений? Включив все необходимые заголовочные файлы?

Comment: @vp_arth: Это не называется "собралось", даже если оно "все таки собралось".

Comment: @ВадимМороз, пожалуйста, вставляйте текст **текстом**, а не картинкой!

Comment: @vp_arth, с миллионом предупреждений от компилятора и даже линковщика.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В дополнение к уже данному ответу.

1. Ваш цикл подсчета слов заканчивается с `istr == NULL`. Затем, в следующем цикле, вы смело продолжаете копировать какую-то строку из `istr`. Что вы хотели этим сказать?
2. В коде присутствует использование функции `strncpy` с целью т.наз. "безопасного копирования строк". Функция `strncpy` для этого не предназначена. Однако если вы уж решили ей воспользоваться в этой роли, то не забывайте добавлять нуль-терминацию вручную

   ```
   strncpy(threadData[i].slovo, istr, 20);
   threadData[i].slovo[19] = '\0';
   ```

   В противном случае, если исходная строка длиннее 19 символов, ваша результирующая строка остается нетерминированной. Если это произошло, то понятно, что вызов `strstr` в потоке будет падать. (В вашем коде именно этого не произойдет, ибо все накроется еще на `gets`, но тем не менее.)

   На Linux у вас также есть под руками `strlcpy` предназначенная именно для безопасного копирования строк без дополнительных "костылей".
3. После того, как вы первым проходом разобрали строку на слова при помощи такого деструктивного метода, как `strtok`, для того, чтобы вторым проходом снова "выцарапать" из разобранной строки эти слова, вам придется сделать ряд [нетривиальных] телодвижений. Я этих телодвижений у вас в коде не вижу.

   Может не стоило использовать `strtok`?
4. Функция `gets` официально удалена из стандартных библиотек С и С++. Забудьте о ее существовании.

Comment: 2. Даже в случае `strlcpy()` никто не отменял необходимость проверки на ошибки. ;)

Comment: @0andriy: Не совсем понятно, о каких именно "ошибках" вы ведете речь.

Comment: Об очевидных, вы привели пример, что строка может быть длинее 19 байт, одной проблемой является нетерминирование, что вы и описали. Второй же, собственно обрезание. Посмотрите, что возвращает `strlcpy()`. И ещё, это всё равно не панацея, если не собирать библиотеку с _FORTIFY_SOURCE.

Comment: @0andriy: Ну это уже мета-вопрос: устраивает ли автора защита от переполнения, основанная на обрезании строки? Я об этом могу лишь гадать. А `_FORTIFY_SOURCE` - тема совершенно ортогональная.

Comment: 1. Так вот именно, в хорошем коде мы обрабатываем эту ошибку, в плохом... ну вы сами видите плохой код.
2. Почему? Это как раз к вопросу об уместности использования `strlcpy()` как таковой. Другое дело, что сейчас найти libc, собранную без этого флага, наверное, тяжело.

Answer (score 3):

Давайте вместе почитаем сообщения компилятора.

> implicit declaration of function FOO

Не включены заголовочные файлы для объявления функции `FOO`. В вашем случае это `<stdlib.h>` и `<unistd.h>` (что нужно для каждой функции - см. `man FOO`)

> warning: ‘return’ with a value, in function returning void

Функция `main()` объявлена как возвращающая ничего (`void`), а в конце стоит `return 0`. Изменить прототип `main()` на корректный.

> warning: the `gets' function is dangerous and should not be used.

Забудьте про эту функцию, в ответе на соседний вопрос было.

Теперь почему может вылезать ошибка. Если у функции нет прототипа, то компилятор C будет считать, что её прототип `int foo()`. И код строить соответственно. Возможно, это и служит причиной ошибки в периоде исполнения. А может и нет :) Но для начала нужно бы с описаными вещами разобраться и собрать программу без предупреждений.

И на будущее: для отлова подобных ошибок в Linux есть немало эффективных средств, начиная с отладчика, трассировщиков, и заканчивая [valgrind](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=valgrind). Осваивать их нужно в обязательном порядке, и чем раньше начнёте, тем лучше. А тут как раз хороший повод начать :)

Comment: Исправил все вышеуказанное, ошибка не исчезла

Comment: Ну так vaigrind/отладчик в руки и вперёд :) Подсказка: при таких входных данных не падает: `S1: "1 2 3", S2: "2"`. А при таких - падает: `S1: "2", S2: "1 2 3"`

Comment: @ВадимМороз, на самом деле  в отладчике чётко виден и момент падения, и причины, ещё до создания потоков.

Comment: @PinkTux, но там же есть `if (strlen(S1) <= strlen(S2))` понятное дело, в первом случае ничего не упадёт. =)

Comment: _"Если у функции нет прототипа, то компилятор C будет считать, что её прототип int foo()."_ - разве? Должен же вывести в соответствии с переданными аргументами? Или ты про возвращаемый тип?